# Is there any way to send a phone number from Desktop browser straight away to dialer?

Tags: android, google-chrome, phone-number, android-dialer

Currently, I have to dial the number manually, sometimes it results in typo error, so I was wondering, if I can highlight the number in my chrome and send the number straight to my android dialer it would be wonderful.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? Give a link on your webpage that will take the user to android dialler?

Comment: I want to avoid manual dialling of the phone number I see on browser webpage, I want something like a chrome extension to send the highlighted part which is a phone number directly to my android dialer, just like syncing it.

Comment: You want to call number from your own webpage or all webpages?

Comment: @AlokNair Any webpages.... which have phone number

Comment: That option is there in android and iphone browsers inbuilt. Wrapping phone numbers in hyperlinks with the tel: schema on webpages will launch dialler app on clicking them. Long pressing number portion will also work on android browser.

Comment: @AlokNair        Sorry for the confusion - I mean Desktop Browser.

Comment: If you are looking for an app with these features and not actually develop app with this idea, then you may have a look at PushBullet. It has a chorme extension and mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Best I could come up with so far... this answer is a work in progress, stay tuned.

## Send to IM app

If you **don't want to install another app** for this purpose but already use a cross-platform IM app you can try to send yourself a message with the phone number, then tap to call when it arrives on your phone.

### WhatsApp Web

`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=`***<your own number>***`&text=Dial this: 0800080808`

<kbd>TODO</kbd> Make bookmarklet

### Webogram (Telegram Web)

`web+tg://msg_url?url=Dial this:&text=0800080808`

⚠ `web+tg://msg?text=Number&to=`***<your own number>*** doesn't work!

<kbd>TODO</kbd> Make bookmarklet

or

## Use Automate for Android

Automate has a [Dial number block](https://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/dial_number.html). I don't get how best to send it the phone number from the Desktop though, in a way that Automate can read. WIP

Explore [Automate for Android ⋅ Community ⋅ Search for "dial"](https://llamalab.com/automate/community/?q=Dial)